# Multiple Page divs background "scrolling"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Using:
jquery Mobile 1.4.5

I want to know if the follow is possible and if so, get a start towards getting it working.

Currently there are  4 page divs that use swipe to navigate between them (transition horizontally)

I would like 1 long background that moves slightly (to the page width) as you move along the containers. Giving the appearance as a smooth scrolling experience and revelling more of the background.

Probably going about this the wrong way but would love some tips.

Cheers!

Comment: Any code of what you done so far?

Comment: You need to at least try something before others will be able to help you.  Post what you have tried and give us something to build on/fix.  Thanks!

Comment: The main issue is that I can't find anything out there to even get started but I will go back to crawling the webs.

Comment: Not really looking for any actual solution or "here is your code sir" Just whether anyone has tried this before or can provide direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that by either setting `background-image` to `body` or page div.

If you set it to `body`, you will get an animated background during transition. You have to make page div `transparent` in that case.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(image.png);
}
.ui-page {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Upon navigating `pagecontainerbeforechange`, get `index()` of the page you are navigating to and multiple it by screen/window width to set new position of the background `background-position-x`.

On first page, `background-position-x` is `0`, we should keep it as is. On `pagecontainercreate` we add `pagecontainerbeforechange` listener to obtain `index()` of the page user navigating to.

```js
$(document).on("pagecontainercreate", function () {
    $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
        if (typeof data.toPage == "object") {
            var index = data.toPage.index(),
                screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
            $("body").animate({
                'background-position-x': "-" + screenWidth * index + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/os2kzfy5/)**

---

Another option is to set `background-image` to page div and on `pagecreate` of each one, we set `background-position-x` also based on page's `index()`.

```css
.ui-page {
  background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {
    var index = $(e.target).index(),
        screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    $(e.target).css({
        "background-position-x": "-" + screenWidth * index + "px"
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/et1khjj7/)**

Comment: Thanks so much Omar, that is exactly what I was looking for and you provided extra information. Much appreciated!

Comment: @SYNACK you're welcome. Second solution works better than first one on safari and chrome.